# What is the difference between Modified Exponential curve and Gompertz curve in Time series anlalysis?

Tags: time-series, curve-fitting

I know the form of a modified exponential and gompertz curve but I cannot understand the difference between the two..How does fitting a gompertz curve differ from that of a modified exponential..please explain..

Comment: Since you know the forms, you know precisely how they differ.  What, then, do you want explained?

Comment: I just know the forms.. y=k+ab^t for modidified exp and y=ka^b^(t) for gompertz..but not sure that how do plotting of points through these different curves yield different conclusions..It would be helpful if explained.